# Using ffmpeg to cut up video into smaller video with exactly 30 frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I need to cut a video with >300 frames into ten videos, where the first video comprises the first 30 frames, the second video comprises frames from 31 to 60 and so on.

Comment: Is it okay to re-encode the video?

Comment: @Mulvya Preserving quality is important. otherwise, we can re-encode it. Hope to find a fast method for this.